# Edit Azure Python code to clean up Speech-to-Text output

Tags: python, azure, speech-to-text

I'm using Microsoft Azure's speech-to-text API and it's working well but the output is cumbersome and I'd like to clean it up so that only the recognized speech is displayed.

[this is what the output looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJ72K.png)

The python snippet that azure provides is:

```
try:
    import azure.cognitiveservices.speech as speechsdk
import sys
sys.exit(1)

speech_key, service_region = "***", "***"

weatherfilename = os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(__file__),
    'orf_audio_2',
    '716_anton.wav')
# def speech_recognize_once_from_file():
    """performs one-shot speech recognition with input from an audio     file"""
# <SpeechRecognitionWithFile>
speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(subscription=speech_key,     region=service_region)
audio_config = speechsdk.audio.AudioConfig(filename=weatherfilename)
# Creates a speech recognizer using a file as audio input.
# The default language is "en-us".
speech_recognizer =     speechsdk.SpeechRecognizer(speech_config=speech_config,     audio_config=audio_config)

start_continuous_recognition() instead.
result = speech_recognizer.recognize_once()

# Check the result
if result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech:
    print("Recognized: {}".format(result.text))
elif result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.NoMatch:
    print("No speech could be recognized: {}".format(result.no_match_details))
elif result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.Canceled:
    cancellation_details = result.cancellation_details
    print("Speech Recognition canceled: {}".format(cancellation_details.reason))
    if cancellation_details.reason == speechsdk.CancellationReason.Error:
        print("Error details: {}".format(cancellation_details.error_details))
# </SpeechRecognitionWithFile>
```

Comment: Not sure what's your meaning. The output only displays `result.text`, no other cumbersome content like your said. What's output you want to get?

Comment: I've edited the question to include an image of the output and more of the code that is provided by azure. I've tried throwing 'result.text' around in the file a few different places but it always seems to provide an error.

Comment: please hide your privacy key immediately! That's a risk for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`result.text` in the sample code is the simplest output of recognized speech.

My test with default microphone:

[image]

---

Please refer to below fragment of code which works for me.

```
import azure.cognitiveservices.speech as speechsdk
import time
# Creates an instance of a speech config with specified subscription key and service region.
# Replace with your own subscription key and service region (e.g., "westus").
speech_key, service_region = "***", "***"

weatherfilename = "D:\\whatstheweatherlike.wav"

speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(subscription=speech_key, region=service_region)
audio_config = speechsdk.audio.AudioConfig(filename=weatherfilename)

# Creates a recognizer with the given settings
speech_recognizer = speechsdk.SpeechRecognizer(speech_config=speech_config, audio_config=audio_config)

speech_recognizer.session_started.connect(lambda evt: print('SESSION STARTED: {}'.format(evt)))
speech_recognizer.session_stopped.connect(lambda evt: print('\nSESSION STOPPED {}'.format(evt)))
speech_recognizer.recognized.connect(lambda evt: print('\n{}'.format(evt.result.text)))

# print('Say a few words\n\n')
speech_recognizer.start_continuous_recognition()
time.sleep(10)
speech_recognizer.stop_continuous_recognition()

speech_recognizer.session_started.disconnect_all()
speech_recognizer.recognized.disconnect_all()
speech_recognizer.session_stopped.disconnect_all()
```

And the output looks like:

[image]

Comment: Thank-you! That worked perfectly. and also thanks for the hiding my privacy key for me! oops.

Comment: @liam You're welcome.BTW,you could mark my answer for others' reference,thank you!